# Installing Qpid-Proton in an Embedded Linux device

Tags: python, azure, embedded-linux, qpid, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to install Qpid-Proton(Python) in an Embedded Linux device to connect with Azure Event Hubs. Previously, I've successfully tested connecting a Linux PC with Azure Event Hubs using the installation steps given in  https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=qpid-proton.git;a=blob_plain;f=INSTALL.md;hb=0.10

To do the same from an Embedded Linux based device, I modified the Linux yocto image to include "pip" installer package and the necessary packages for the Qpid-proton installation using a Linux PC.

Using that image, I tried to do the second part of the installation (from creating 'build' directory) in the board. It fails during cmake part throwing the error as:

$ cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/bin .. -DSYSINSTALL_BINDINGS=ON

-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc" is not able to compile
  a simple test program.

P.S: I'm a beginner in Linux and have done all the above by googling for it. If there is any procedure to install Qpid in an embedded linux device, please share it with me. Thank you.

Comment: What's your embedded Linux device?

Comment: Hi, it's a Freescale i.MX6(Solo) based board. I successfully sent a sample data using Python script to Azure Event Hubs (installed azure in the device using pip) and to receive data, I'm trying to use Qpid-proton.

Comment: You can try to command `pip install python-qpid-proton` to install qpid-proton.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your embedded device is, what embedded Linux preinstalled packages are.

So I don't think I can help building the qpid lib from source code. And I think it's not a good idea without toturials for a begginner in embedded linux.

But If your embedded device is Raspberry Pi or BeagleBone, I think you can refer to this page http://brentonc.com/2015/05/03/how-to-send-events-from-a-raspberry-pi-to-microsoft-azure-event-hubs/ to install azure python sdk by using tool pip to access Event Hubs.

However, the simple  practial way to using Azure Event Hubs on Embedded System is to use Event Hubs REST APIs via HTTP per my experience. I had successfully sent messages into Event Hubs via HTTP REST APIs on Arduino Ethernet and Raspberry Pi.

About Event Hubs REST APIs, you can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790674.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn170477.aspx.

Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the info Peter. Yeah, I've already gone through those links. Sending messages to event hub is not a problem but receiving does. I used the Azure SDK for Python in my device for sending message to Event Hub (using send_event api) but can't do the same for receiving. Is there any option similar to send_event, (eg: receive_event) to receive msgs from Event hubs or any other way to receive?

Comment: @RamPrasad There is no option to receive msgs by using azure sdk & rest api for python. But MS support Event Processor Host API in C# to receive event. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-c-ephcs-getstarted/#receive-messages-with-eventprocessorhost.